# Is this expression positive or negative

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For consecutive, positive, odd integers $a,b$, and $c$ (where $a<b<c$) is the sign of the following expression positive or negative?

$(c-a)(b-a)(c-b)(a-c)(a-b)(b-c)$

where: $a<b<c$

Answer (score 1):

Recall that by definition, $(x>y \implies x-y >0$ (is positive). When $x \lt y, \;x - y < 0$ (is negative). Applying this to your product,

$$a<b<c \implies \underbrace{(c-a)}_{+}\underbrace{(b-a)}_{+}\underbrace{(c-b)}_{+}\underbrace{(a-c)}_{-}\underbrace{(a-b)}_{-}\underbrace{(b-c)}_{-} < 0$$

When all factors are positive or negative, multiplying by an odd number of negative factors produces a negative result.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$(c-a)(b-a)(c-b)(a-c)(a-b)(b-c)=-[(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)]^2$$